# where to find cassandra.thrift file?

Tags: php, cassandra, thrift-protocol

i am trying to use apache thrift to connect cassandra by PHP.

after i followed these [steps](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ThriftExamples), finally i run this command:

```
thrift -gen php interface/cassandra.thrift
```

but an error occured :

[FAILURE:arguments:1] Could not open input file with realpath: interface/cassandra.thrift

I cannot find where is the cassandra.thrift file ?

is there anybody that knows where is this file or what is wrong with my proccess ?

operating system ubuntu 
command path : ext/thrift/

```
thrift -r --gen php tutorial.thrift
```

works fine, but cassandra.thrift is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can get the file from the cassandra documentation...

https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ThriftInterface

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cassandra/trunk/interface/cassandra.thrift

Comment: should i get all cassandar folder  or just cassandra.thrift file ? if i have to use cassandra folder, where should i place it ?

Comment: no the "interface/cassandra.thrift" is just the path to the file, if its in the same folder as you are currently in then just run `thrift -gen php cassandra.thrift`